# Casting a void pointer at runtime

Tags: c

I am trying to make a certain function more generic. I wrote the function to use two parameters of pointer to type uint32_t. One of the parameters is the data to read (and send to a TCP server) and the other parameter is meant to read store data received back from the server. Here is the prototype for the function:

```
int write2server(uint32_t *data2write, size_t size, uint32_t *recieveBuffer){

        sendData(data2write, size, TIME_OUT); //sends the data to server
        recieveData(recieveBuffer);
}
```

The above function includes some other functions. The details are not important, I'm just trying to show how I use the data2write array to send data to the server and store data received back in my recieveBuffer. My calling function provides the data to send and the recieve buffer. Now, I am interested in the case where I am actually writing and reading data of type **uint16_t** instead. I thought the natural thing to do is to make the parameters void pointers so that it can be generic. I would then add a switch construct to the function and cast the void pointers as needed. An additional parameter (int typeID) would be passed to indicate data type. Below is a general idea:

```
int write2server(void *data2write, size_t size, void *recieveBuffer, int typeID){
         switch(typeID){
             case 0:
                  sendData((uint32_t*)data2write, size, TIME_OUT); //sends the data to server
                  recieveData((uint32_t*)recieveBuffer);
                  break;
             case 1:
                   sendData((uint16_t*)data2write, size, TIME_OUT); //sends the data to server
                   recieveData((uint16_t*)recieveBuffer);
                   break;
             default:
                   break;
         } 
    }
```

**Is this approach valid? Or is this something not allowed in C?**

**EDIT, I removed the endian conversion function, people were getting to excited and distracted by that. This is just pseudo code, please focus on the main question**

Thanks

Comment: The arguments to the functions you call have to be the types it expects. If `convertEndian()` is declared to accept `uint32_t*`, you can't pass it `uint16_t*`.

Comment: So you either need two functions, `convertEndian32()` and `convertEndian16()`, or you should also modify `convertEndian()` so it takes `void*` and `typeID` parameters and performs a similar dispatch.

Comment: The general approach is valid but, as noted by @Barmar, you have issues with the functions called by your function - what are the arguments to those supposed to be?

Comment: What is the interpretation of the `size` parameter?  Is it intended to count bytes or `uint32_t` words?

Comment: In the `convertEndian()` function, you need to know whether it's 16 bits or 32 bits, so you know whether to use `htons()` or `htonl()`.

Comment: Don't worry about convertEndian, just look at the overall question, is the approach valid? Also, size denotes size of the message in bytes.

Comment: Doesn't `sendData` also take a void pointer, and `receiveData`? You can just send the same void pointer to those functions. No need to cast it.

Comment: There is still a call to `convertEndian` in the code. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Harking back to the original version that calls `convertEndian`, it is kind of bad design for the `write2server` function to modify the data buffer that is passed to it.

Comment: @TestEngineer11 It's not just `convertEndian()`, you have the same problem with `sendData()` and `recieveData()` -- you have to call them with their declared types. BTW, "i before e, except after c".

Comment: Not what you asked, but:  As either the implementor or the caller of a function like `write2server`, I would find it much more convenient if there were two separate functions, `write2server16` and `write2server32`, and if the `size` argument counted words, not bytes.  I don't see the benefit of trying to have a single, overloaded `write2server` function -- it seems more troublesome and confusing than it's worth.

Comment: @Barmar, those other functions are functions from the LabWindows/CVI library that accept pointers to any data array. The function internally handles it as needed.

Comment: But you have to cast to the type it wants.

Comment: @SteveSummit, you raise a good point, this is something I considered as well. Also, the actual functions are much larger, so what you suggested seems to make more sense.

Comment: I think your solution is perfectly valid. Only the meaning of `size` must be clearer to the caller, as @SteveSummit suggested. If you want to make generic functions for typed parameters, you can use `_Generic`.

Comment: You misspell the word "receive".

Answer (score 1):

Basically for each data type you support, you need a specific version for each of your 3 functions `convertEndian`, `sendData` and `recieveData`, also you don't need to explicitly cast from void pointers to other pointers.

```
int write2server(void *data2write, size_t size, void *recieveBuffer, int typeID){
     switch(typeID){
         case 0:
              convertEndian_u32(data2write, size); //a function for endian conversion
              sendData_u32(data2write, size, TIME_OUT); //sends the data to server
              recieveData_u32(recieveBuffer);
              break;
         case 1:
               convertEndian_u16(data2write, size); //a function for endian conversion
               sendData_u16(data2write, size, TIME_OUT); //sends the data to server
               recieveData_u16(recieveBuffer);
               break;
         default:
               break;
     } 
}
```

Comment: You generally don't need type-specific versions of send/receive functions, because they just work at the byte level -- the endian conversion function takes care of getting everything into the correct order of bytes.

Comment: Don't use `0`,`1`, ... for it, make an enum